# Detect changes in database and refresh webpage

Tags: html, mysql

I'm currently receive information to populate a webpage from a MySQL database. However, this data is regularly updated by other users of the application. So, to ensure everyone has the latest update on their screen, I would like the code to detect a change in the table and if so, reload the webpage.

`<a href="squawk.php?remove=yes&squawkr=<?php echo $sectionsquawk; ?>"><div class="button-used"><?php echo $sectionsquawk; ?></div></a><span class="input"><?php echo $acheck['callsign']; ?></span>`

So, whenever the 'callsign' row in the table changes, I would like it to refresh the webpage.

Thx.

Comment: youll need to use ajax and jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you use a cache method (this explain reason that make your webpage not real time updated) you can reset / delete cache when you update database.